# Is TCAS II required in the US?

Tags: faa-regulations, safety, aircraft-systems

I would like to know if, in addition to any MEL requirements, there is any regulation or requirement about having an operational TCAS II while operating in US airspace?

Comment: If EEUU means the US, it's better to use the English abbreviation than the Spanish one.

Answer (score 3):

TCAS II is required for most airline flights. This is not a requirement for certification, and the TCAS may or may not be on the MEL. However, most flights under part 121 (scheduled airline service, as well as some freight) require TCAS II.

As noted in [FAR 121.356](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=1ba894a9fff26716db7d7ef0733c7e8e&mc=true&node=se14.3.121_1356&rgn=div8), "Turbine-powered airplane of more than 33,000 pounds maximum certificated takeoff weight" must be operated with equipment that meets a list of standards, but is essentially equivalent to just requiring TCAS II. Smaller aircraft with 10-30 seats can use TCAS-I.

Answer (score -2):

No.  It's not required in the United States.  There is nothing in Part 25 of the regulations.  However, if you install one it should comply with this AC.

www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/20-151B.pdf

Comment: Part 25 covers the design of the aircraft, Part 121 covers the operation. There are many things not required in a Part 25 aircraft but required to operate it under Part 121 and similar. Systems like TCAS are some examples.